# One bison parser with multiple flex scanners

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have this project where I want to use `bison` for parsing together with multiple`flex` scanners. The language I want to parse contains specific pair of tags which define area in the text that should be parsed differently. The thing is that this area define a little bit different tokens than the *parent language* so it cannot really be scanned with one scanner and I want to avoid using multiple bison parsers if it is possible, however I will if I really have to.

So what I've done so far. I have created two reentrant `flex` scanners with two different prefixes, let's say `aa` and `bb`. When initalizing these scanners using `aaset_in` resp. `bbset_in`, I have used the same `FILE*` pointer. In my parser, I have defined midrule action `switchToBbScanner` in the appropriate rule of my grammar. I have defined my own `yylex` so it checks which scanner is active right now and calls `aalex` resp. `bblex` depending on the chosen scanner.

But every time the `bb` scanner reads the token I get something like this

`--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--accepting rule at line 26 ("abc")
--accepting rule at line 27 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 23 ("=")
--accepting rule at line 27 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 24 ("{")
Switching to BB
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
--EOF (start condition 0)
syntax error, unexpected END, expecting HEXDIGIT`

Is it even possible to achieve something like this? I tried debugging code generated by `flex` but I am struggling with understanding all the macro code. Since minimal example is huge to paste it here, I have made a repo https://github.com/metthal/so-minimal-example with it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how you found it but it seems like something that could help me. Thanks! How to deal with this situation now? Should I answer my question or just let it be?

Comment: If the other answer helped you upvote it. Eventually someone will link the questions so you don't need to do anything else. Finding the other answer was easy because I wrote it last week :-)